a docker container oauth 2 server nodejs docker image
we need an authentication layer for our docker file.
we want to have a docker container that its port is 8888. we want a layer which contains traefik and enable us to have an access to traefik layer by port 8080. by using index.html can connect to traefik layer. in html page by using of oauth2 enables to do authentication.
by using this link we didn't reach any result.
https://www.ory.sh/run-oauth2-server-open-source-api-security/
